# Extract date from a reference

Tags: r, date, extract

I would like to extract the date of a Column reference (i want to pass from (21510000XXX -> 10/2015). The problem is that, the references for the years 2015 and 2016 are not the same respect to the year 2017.

It is like that:

```
DF<-c(21612000675, 21612000494, 20170100011, 21507000583, 21508000306)
```

> DF
>   [1] 21612000675 21612000494 20170100011 21507000583 21508000306

The first one is year 2016, month 12 ("216","12" number)), the third is diferent, as all 2017, so year 2017, month 01 ("2017", "01", number), the last one, as year 2015, is the same as year 2016, so year 2015 month 08 ("2015", "08", number)

Comment: I did not understand very well what you want. Do you want to clean the data, is that it? I mean, do you want to make the dates to be written with the same pattern? Or do you want to extract specific dates from the column? It is not very clear.

Comment: I want to extract the year and the month of each reference "20170100XX -> 01/2017"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

ym <- str_extract(DF, '^(215|216|2017)[0-9]{2}') %>%
        gsub(pattern = '^215', replacement = '2015') %>%
        gsub(pattern = '^216', replacement = '2016') %>%
        gsub(pattern = '(20[0-9]{2})', replacement = '\\1\\/')
> ym
[1] "2016/12" "2016/12" "2017/01" "2015/07" "2015/08"
```

EDIT:

If you wanna months before years try:

```
ym <- str_extract(DF, '^(215|216|2017)[0-9]{2}') %>%
        gsub(pattern = '^215', replacement = '2015') %>%
        gsub(pattern = '^216', replacement = '2016') %>%
        gsub(pattern = '(20[0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})', replacement = '\\2\\/\\1')
> ym
[1] "12/2016" "12/2016" "01/2017" "07/2015" "08/2015"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try making the patterns consistent. For example,

```
gsub("^(21)(5|6)", "\\10\\2", DF)
> [1] "210612000675" "210612000494" "20170100011"  "210507000583" "210508000306"
```

Take a look at `?gsub`.

The first argument is the pattern to match, in this case any string that **begins with** the string `21` followed by **either** `5` or `6`, hence `^(21)(5|6)`.

The second argument is the substitution, in this case place a `0` between the first and second "capture groups" in your pattern. The third argument is what you want to modify.

Comment: Once you standardize the strings, you can use `gsub` again to get your `MM/YYYY` format: `gsub("^(\\d{4})(\\d{2}).*", "\\2/\\1", DF)`